# Integral over a torus

Tags: differential-geometry, integration, manifolds

I've been asked to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{\mathbb{T}^2} xyz \, dw\wedge dy$$
where $\mathbb{T}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ is the 2-torus defined by: $$w^2+x^2=y^2+z^2=1$$
I've tried "double" polar coordinates, but haven't reach anything. Any tips?

Comment: I think "double" polar coordinates can solve this integral. I cannot understand where you are stuck.

Comment: Mm the only problem is that the result I get is zero, I expected something cooler hehe, but I think I'll have to take it.

Comment: Is there an argument from symmetry showing this integral is $0$ without using polar coordinates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple symmetry argument: $(w,x,y,z) \mapsto (-w,x,-y,z)$ is an orientation-preserving symmetry of the torus which preserves $dw \wedge dy$ and maps $xyz$ to $-xyz$, so the integral $I$ has to satisfy $I=-I$, hence $I=0$.

Comment: Why does the symmetry $(w,x,y,z) \mapsto (w,-x,y,z)$ preserve $dw \wedge\ dy$?

Comment: @Vessemir: Just by the transformation formula for differential forms. Note that the $w$ and $y$ variable do not change under this transformation, so $dw$ and $dy$ don't either, and neither does their wedge product.

Comment: @LukasGeyer I hope it's ok that I ask a question 10+ years later. I would think that this transformation is orientation preserving, and therefore the transformation formula would yield $\int \omega=-\int\phi^*\omega=\int\omega$ where $\omega=xyz dw\wedge dy$. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: @ShaVuklia: I think you mean that the transformation is orientation-reversing, which gives the minus sign, and yes, this seems to be a mistake in my answer. There is an easy fix, though, replacing the transformation by the orientation-preserving map $(w,x,y,z) \mapsto (-w,x,-y,z)$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer I made a typo indeed, thanks, that works! :)

Answer (score 7):

Choose local coordinates $(\theta, \phi) \in (0,2\pi) \times (0,2\pi)$ where $w = \cos\theta, x = \sin\theta, y = \cos\phi, z = \sin\phi$.  Then you can just pullback the integral to $(0,2\pi) \times (0,2\pi)$ since the complement of this chart in $T^2$ is of measure zero.

We have $dw = -\sin\theta \, d\theta,\ dy = -\sin\phi \, d\phi$.  So you end up with
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2\theta\cos\phi\sin^2\phi \, d\theta \, d\phi,
$$
which is a fairly straightforward integral ($u$-sub for the $\phi$ part and half angle for the $\theta$ part).

Comment: yep, you get the same result with a similar method, thanks a lot!